# How to get s3 bucket policy update in cloud trail logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

Hi I have created a bucket and enabled cloud trail also including s3 object level api logging. 
Now when I create some s3 ACL via UI the I get the logs in cloud trail but when I Create the same ACL via json Bucket->permissions -> bucket policy (And enter my JSON value and save) then this is not getting tracked

Comment: There is some delay between events and them appearing in CloudTrail. Everything in AWS is an API call, the console makes them on your behalf, so if CloudTrail is turned on the events will be recorded.

Comment: No even after a long time the log is not appearing in CloudTrail espically when I do it via bucket policy editor via console , but if the same I do via api call then it works. Usually I get all logs in CloudTrail within 10 to 15 min

Comment: I got the issue it doesn't log with root user activity , If I use other user then the log appears

Comment: CloudTrail is meant to log all API calls, regardless of the user who does them. I would like for you to post this on the AWS forums to have this validated and ask if it's a bug.